# How to set a linkage tag for .mp3 file in Adobe Animate

Tags: flash, adobe, createjs, animate-cc

I have an Adobe Animate file. I am trying to set a linkage tag to the .mp3 file in the library that that I can use something like this

```
createjs.Sound.play("mySound");
```

For other objects in the library I am able to click on the linkage area of the objet and type in my name. But for the .mp3 its opening up the Sound Properties. I have seen examples with the linkage set, but haven't figure out a way to set the linkage property myself. Here is a screen grab of where I'm talking about.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of including the .mp3 file in the .fla itself, I find it much more proper to put your sound file/s in an external folder and then load it like:

```
createjs.Sound.on("fileload", handleFileLoad);
createjs.Sound.registerSound("[path/]MySound.mp3", "MySound");

function handleFileLoad()
{
    createjs.Sound.play("MySound");
}
```

By doing so, you can assign the sound file to a variable and then manipulating it, like volume, number of loops or adding "complete" events to it.

Also, if you have multiple sound files, you can preload them all at once using the manifest loader, which will also automatically register them for playing by using their "id" at any time.

Answer (score 3):

This is actually really easy. You can double click item in the "Linkage" column to add a name. Once you do this, the audio will be included in your application when exported.

Demo: https://youtu.be/wQ5zm6QHHMU

If you have at least one sound (as a linkage or on a frame), SoundJS and the `playSound` helper method are included in your HTML. However, if you have none, then your app won't have any of this.

Once exported, you can use either method:

```
createjs.Sound.play("linkage-id");
// OR
playSound("linkage-id");
```

The other answer by @Catalin is also correct -- you can manage audio yourself, which may make sense for a larger project.

Cheers.

Comment: For some reason it will not allow me to click on the linkage area, I tried and it just keeps bringing up the properties. It was really easy to set the linkage for a movieclip, but this audio files doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: What version of Animate are you using?

Comment: I am using Animate CC 2017